# How to reload in the default Android emulator for react native app

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

I am using default Android emulator for running react native apps, I need to reload the app frequently, how do I do that?

And how can I set genymotion to set as default emulator for app running?

Comment: if you're using macos BigSur then you might want to look at this too . https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Answer (score 122, accepted):

For **android** one can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
For **apple** one can use <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (two times `R`).

For developers options:
One can also use the <kbd>Command⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut when your app is running in the **iPhone Simulator**, or <kbd>Command⌘</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> when running in an **Android emulator**.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why me double-tapping "R" on my keyboard wouldn't work? I got a Mac running the simulator perfectly fine. I know it sees my keystrokes because I can initiate multi-tap via cmd. It's just weird that I can't seem to trigger a refresh.

Comment: @SmokinJoe me too. I must use Command+M like rajat44 suggests and choose Enable Live Reload.

Comment: @SmokinJoe, make sure in your Android Studio, Tools->Android->AVD Manager->Virtual Device Configuration->Enable keyboard input checkbox is checked. Then try run emulator again, then have a try. and I found I have to double tap R very quickly, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Сonversely `CTRL +R` for android. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#reloading-javascript

Comment: For me on macOS on an Android emulator, `CTRL + R` does **not** work, only `R + R` does.

Comment: I'm having problem pressing Cmd+M does nothing, also double tap R does nothing, but they're working on my other project in the same local machine. What is possibly wrong with it?

Answer (score 51):

I tried in this way:

1. Open Android Studio, then Click Tools->Android->AVD Manager, as shown:[image]
2. Choose your virtual devices, then click edit this AVD,[image]
3. In Virtual Device Configuration, click Show Advanced Settings, scroll down to
   find Keyboard, then check **Enable keyboard input** checkbox, then click Finish button.[image]
   [image]
4. Launch this AVD in emulator.[image]
5. In Terminal, in your react native project directory, run "react-native run-android".
6. Your will see your app will be running in your emulator, if you want to reload the project, you could double tap R(**you should type it very quickly**, otherwise it may not reload js) or you can type **command+M**, then you choose **Reload**.
   [image]
   Hope this will help.
   Cheers

Comment: R+R (no modifier key) is the secret keyboard shortcut. Thanks!

Comment: For Android, too - thx @Ajnas Kt for the tip

Answer (score 46):

R+R works for android emulators.

Comment: Works in Windows too.  The trick is to type R+R quickly enough.

Answer (score 22):

to open dev menu with command line: `adb shell input keyevent 82`

you can activate live reload there.

[I would suggest reading the doc if it wasn't already been done](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/running-on-device-android.html)

Comment: The usb port on my device is really sloppy, so I can't shake it (which breaks the packager and ruins everything). I created an alias in /home/<USER>/.bashrc: `alias adbmenu='adb shell input keyevent 82'`. It has so far proved reliable. Otherwise I cannot enable hot reloading.

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed Mellouki. Your solution is working for me.

Answer (score 12):

Press `Ctrl + m`, a menu will pop.

for further ease. `Enable Hot Reloading`: whenever you make changes in your code it will reload itself; You won't have to reload again and again.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For Android emulator press "CTRL + M" with keyboard on emulator for reloading the react native project.

Answer (score 1):

On my mac the dev menu is shown using the "fn" key + M

Comment: for me (2022) it was FN + CMD + M

Comment: For me (Sept 2023) it was just cmd + M

Answer (score 0):

If you are emulating on windows using npm, open your command line running the process and press r.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you built a development build and not a production build! I spent far too long on this only to realize that I was trying to pull up the dev menu on a production build.