# Reload a React Native app on an Android device manually via command line

Tags: react-native

I'd like to manually force a Reload of my React Native app on demand without physically shaking the device. (I'm getting carpal tunnel.)

I know that Live Reload / Hot Reload are available. I'm looking for a on-demand command line solution.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Using the cmd line you can send a command to the Android device.

```
adb shell input text "RR"
```

This command tells the Android device to type the character "R" twice which is the React Native command to Reload on Android.

The `adb shell` command has many useful features many of which are described here:

[ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

To open the developer menu:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Comment: For anyone who is having issues with the first command (in cases like a text input which cannot be unfocused), an alternative is `adb shell "input keyevent 82 && input keyevent 66 && input keyevent 66"`. It manually hits 'Reload' in the developer menu

Comment: Incase you are running 2 devices at the same time and it doesn't let you run any `adb` commands you can simply do: `adb -s <device nane> shell input text "RR"`

Answer (score 26):

Just posting it here in case you didn't know this trick

**long press the menu button** in your android device. Then you'll get this menu

[image]

**tap the reload option** and you are good to go

Comment: my android mobile don't have menu button. is there any alternatives for my device?

Comment: "How can I reload without shaking my device?" @OsmanGaniKhanMasum: "Just shake your device."

Comment: You can just enable "Hard Reload" from settings. It is easy.

Comment: Nice. On my Fire TV remote, I don't even have to long press, just a regular press.

Comment: You can hold and press Square button, at bottom navigation bar in android. In some device Round button works.

Answer (score 15):

I use the following command. It doesn't reload the app, but it brings up the developper menu on the device, so I can then press the "Reload" option:

`adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU`

I develop with a real device (not the emulator) and sending the "double-R" through adb doesn't work (it just shows the keyboard and types 2 Rs).

Comment: That's interesting, because I develop on a real device too and the "double-R" does reload the app. If the keyboard is already open it will print "RR", but if the keyboard is closed it will reload. Maybe my answer was too general and doesn't work on all devices?

Comment: @brettlaforge I'm a newb at native but I might guess that certain apps may be greedy about keypresses, not just different devices. Your answer's working for me on Android so thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Add the following script to your package.json:

```
    "android-shake": "adb shell input keyevent 82"
```

Then you will be able to call

```
yarn android-shake
```

If you are looking for ios then checkout my answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839666/how-do-i-open-react-natives-dev-menu-on-real-device/53436424#53436424)

Answer (score 5):

One trick would be to add this command on ~/.bashrc profile in the case you're using unix.

1. use your favorite editor (ex: nano on Ubuntu) and type `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. on the end of file write `alias rnreload='adb shell input text "RR"'`
3. save it and run `source ~/.bashrc` in order to active it.
4. Now whenever you need, just type `rnreload` on a terminal.

Next time you enter your computer it should be already done.

Also, there's the possibility to add an other alias as well: `alias rnshake='adb shell input keyevent 82'` which "shakes" android. You can use it to access other commands like Hot Reloading, Debugger, Inspector, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Made an autohotkey script to reload and open the menu with keyboard shortcuts.

```
   ^+r::  run, %comspec% /c adb shell input text "RR",,hide  
   ^+e::  run, %comspec% /c adb shell input keyevent 82,,hide
```

ctrl+shift+r to reload
ctrl+shift+e to open dev menu

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac and using [Hammerspoon](http://hammerspoon.org/), you can put the following bit of code in your `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` file:

```
hyper = {'ctrl', 'alt', 'cmd'}
placid = {'ctrl', 'cmd'}

-- React native reload JS on connected device
hs.hotkey.bind(placid, 'R', function()
  os.execute('/Users/peter/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell input text "RR"')
end)

-- React native show dev menu on connected device
hs.hotkey.bind(hyper, 'R', function()
  os.execute('/Users/peter/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell input keyevent 82')
end)
```

the `os.execute` command doesn't load your ENV (doing so would make running commands really slow), so make sure to run `which adb` in your terminal to figure out what the exact path to `adb` is. (in my case it was `/Users/peter/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`).

Now you can reload your app using `ctrl+cmd+R` and show the dev menu using `ctrl+option+cmd+R` from anywhere and without even bothering to cmd-tab out of your favorite editor!

Answer (score -1):

For device you have just to shake your device than a menu appears so click on Reload

Comment: It is mentioned in the question: _"without physically shaking the device"_