# reload on physical device - react native

Tags: react-native

I want to make some changes to my JS code and then *reload* that change on the physical device

it works fine on emulator/simulator but when I make the change to my JS files and reload from *Debug Menu* nothing changed so I go to *xCode* or *Android Studio* and re-run the app again(and this takes a lot of time)

---

- I appreciate  any improvement to my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170991/reload-a-react-native-app-on-an-android-device-manually-via-command-line

Answer (score 1):

On Android you can shake the device to load the developer menu.
Then you can reload.

The following link has detailed instructions for ios & android.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you use React Native Debugger and you have it connected to the device, you can hit command+R with that screen in focus to refresh...works on Andriod and iOS physical devices.

Answer (score -1):

If viewing on a web browser, can you try clearing your cache? During a build a compiler cleans the project removing old compiled objects and creating new ones.

If building through the command line, use the `clean` command to make sure nothing is persisting between builds.